# asynchronous code to nested synchronous manner in Meteor/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, meteor, async-await

I have been trying to run data fetching code in a `container` component and pass it to the `display` one to reduce using hooks and load time. I tried both `await/sync` and Meteor's `wrapAsync` [Here is its Docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync) but I admit I dont really understand this function.

**N.B:**  The code is pseudo code that explains the basic structure and functionality I need to apply, everything has been imported properly. The code structure and order is the same as the actual code. Thats what matters

**Current Result**

display component errors out as `undefined` because the `data` or `t1Doc` are empty

**Container async/await**

```
const Container = withTracker(({ id, ...rest }) => {
  const t1Handle = Meteor.subscribe("table1");
  const t2Handle = Meteor.subscribe("table2");
  const isLoading = !t1Handle.ready() && !t2Handle.ready();
  const fetchT1Documents = async () => {
  const t1Doc = await t1Collection.findOne(query);
  let t2Doc;
  const fetchT2Documents = async () => {
    t2Doc = await t2Collection.findOne(t1Doc.FK);
  }
  fetchT2Documents();
  parseXmltoJs(t1Doc, (err, result) => {
    fetchAjaxData(result,t2Doc)
    .then((data) => {
    return {
      isLoading,
      t1Doc,
      t2Doc,
      data
    }
  })
});
  }
  fetchT1Documents();
    
  return {
    isLoading,
    t1,
    ...rest,
  };
})(WithLoading(displayComponent));
```

**Loader**

```
const WithLoading = (Comp) => ({ isLoading, children, ...props }) => {
  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loader />;
  } else {
    return (
      <Fade in={true} timeout={500}>
        <div>
          <Comp {...props}>{children}</Comp>
        </div>
      </Fade>
    );
  }
};

export { WithLoading };
```

sorry for the bad editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips on this one...

You can make a publication that publishes more than one collection/query, eg table1 and table2. It returns a single handle, that is ready when both collections have data.

No need to do an await on the `collection.findOne()` calls - these are calls to minimongo (client side cache), and will return either `null` when the subscription is loading, and will return the data otherwise.

The pattern you are using is excellent, and allows separation of display logic from the grubby data layer :)